# ProcessException not available in Winter '21 environment

Tags: process-builder, deployment, process, winter21

I have been having issues with the new ProcessException object. It’s available on API v. 50. I have 2 sandboxes that I’m deploying between (the process exception layout, profile metadata, and sharing rules, and the object), and they are both on Winter `21. Source org is Enterprise Edition and the target is Unlimited Edition. However, the deployment fails and it seems like I can’t access Process Exceptions in my target higher environment. How can I enable this object?

Comment: Check if 'Process Exceptions' object permission is enabled on the profile under 'Standard Object Permissions' in your org.

Comment: In the target org I can't even see Process Exception on the profile screen, although I can in the source org. I even queried the object in the developer console in both orgs, the target org said the object was unavailable while the source org was able to query successfully.

Comment: Process Exception is available in Enterprise, Unlimited, and Developer Editions,  Can you re-check your target org edition? (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=om_process_exception_management.htm&type=5)

Comment: I double checked company information and sure enough it's unlimited. Running on CS18 if that makes a difference